# Proof that direct distance from $a$ to $b$ is at most the distance of any other path from $a$ to $b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

> **Lemma 1**. If the triangle inequality holds in a graph with positive
>   weights, then d(a, b) is at most the weight of any path from a to b.
>
> **Proof**. We prove the lemma by induction. Let the inductive hypothesis P
>   (n) be the statement “If n is the length of a path p from a to b, for
>   any vertices a and b, then d(a, b) is at most the weight of p.”
>
> This
>   holds for the base case of n = 1, since the minimum cost of traveling
>   from a to b cannot be strictly greater than the weight of the direct
>   path from a to b (otherwise, we could simply take the direct path for
>   a smaller cost).

In the above proof I know the base case is true because if length of path $p$ is $1$, then $d(a, b)= \text{weight of } p$.

However I can't understand their reasoning which states:
 $\text{minimum cost of travelling from a to b } \le d(a,b)$

**EDIT:** Graph is complete graph and $d(a,b)$ is known for each pair of vertices, where $d(a,b)$ is the weight of edge $a-b$.

Comment: What is the definition of $d(a,b)$?

Comment: I assume that the "minimum cost of travelling" is simply the minimum of *distance*".

Comment: It is the weight of edge a-b.

Comment: @shiva From your answer, I deduce that there is at most one edge between any two vertices. So for the case $n=1$ there is really nothing to show, because the only path with length $1$ *is* the edge connecting $a$ and $b$. Anyway, either you have misunderstood some definition, or the above proof is really not very sensibly formulated.

Comment: I actually think that $d(a,b)$ should be the infimum of the weights of all the paths leading from $a$ to $b$. Then this definition would make sense even if there is no edge between $a$ and $b$. But then the statement of the lemma would be tautological

Comment: With this modification, the lemma should read "if there is an (always unique) edge $p$ between $a$ and $b$, then $d(a,b) = w(p)$", and the proof of it would be again the one from my answer.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please look.

Comment: This does not change my answer. What they are saying is just that by triangle inequality the direct path is the shortest, which is what I have proved below.

Comment: @57Jimmy However I had trouble understanding their reasoning for the base case.

Comment: I know, but the point is really that their argument does not make sense: they are doing an induction, but the explanation they give for the base case is actually a general explanation (whereas for the base case one does not need any explanation: if everything is as you have defined it, there is *only one* path of length $1$ between $a$ and $b$, and it is the edge connecting them). And the general explanation is: "if you can travel along a path and your cost of travelling (i.e., the sum of the weights / distances) is smaller than $d(a,b)$, then the triangle inequality cannot hold".

Comment: Without any offence, I really think that either you are missing some part of some definition, or the proof (as you stated it) does not make sense.

Comment: None taken. And its highly probable that I might have missed something. Here is the source: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/recitations/MIT6_042JF10_rec09_sol.pdf. If you get time then you can go through it, won't take much time.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from repeated application of triangle inequality (without explicitly using induction). Indeed, if you have any path $p$ from $a$ to $b$ consisting of $n$ edges $p_i$ connecting vertices $c_{i-1}$ to $c_i$ (hence $c_0=a, c_n=b$), and if $w$ denotes the weight function, then you have

$$d(a,b) \le \sum_i d(c_{i-1},c_i) = \sum_i w(p_i) = w(p).$$